# Creating Volume in a body

Tags: reverse-engineering, siemens-nx

I've been forming sheets and it is now a completely covered solid with no volume in it. Its basically 6 sheets, in something like a cube form. Currently it is filled with nothing, with no volume. My goal is to have it filled with volume in the cubic shape that i formed, using NX11.

Answer (score 0):

If you **sew** your sheets, and they form a closed surface, it will be automatically a solid.